# Property name with value in ICS file to set Out of Office event type in Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

Can you please give me an advice, what is the correct property name with value (if there any is) for .ics file to display Out of Office status/event type in Google calendar ?
Based on Google calendar API [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events), there is just attribute "eventType" with values and it does not work.

This is .ics file example with "eventType" attribute in:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0

PRODID:-//Client Events//NONSGML Client Events//EN
URL: https://portal.com/
REFRESH-INTERVAL;VALUE=DURATION:PT12H
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT12H
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST

BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
SEQUENCE:1
ORGANIZER:info@email.com
CREATED:20220504T070932Z
DTSTAMP:20220504T070932Z
DTSTART:20220520T130000Z
DTEND:20220520T143000Z
SUMMARY:Vacation
LOCATION:TULIP
DESCRIPTION:I am on vacation. \n\n\n
UID:AttendanceRequestIfddf97981654254D33260@https://portal.com/
EVENTTYPE:OUTOFOFFICE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

Thank you.